# Is there a code to find the longest period of time without out any interference or overlapping?

Tags: python

I need to find a python code to find **biggest periods of time doesn't** matter the gaps.

For example:

```
 _________(15 days)__________
1                           15
                                                               _______(23 days)__________
                                                              100                      122
             ____________(50 days)____________
            10                              59
                                                                        ___________(70 days)___________
                                                                       115                          184
```

This problem is the time line contains the days that some item will be busy. 
I want to find a way to make some item as busy as possible.
Well I mean the timeline **from day 10 to day 59 (50 days)** + the time line **from day 115 to day 184 (70 day)** can make item busy for about **120 days** which is the largest combination to produce longest days.
I want to extract that from the previous timeline:

```
            _____________(50 days)____________                         ___________(70 days)___________
            10                              59                         115                          184
```

This is the dictionary which I represented as a timeline above and the interference or overlapping.

```
interference_dict = {
 1: {'time': 15, 'interference':[3]} ,  
 2: {'time': 23, 'interference':[4]} ,  
 3: {'time': 50, 'interference':[1]} ,  
 4: {'time': 70, 'interference':[2]}  
}
```

Then I tried to calculate possible combinations time **without** interference by the following code:

```
profits = []
for schedule_id, data in interference_dict.items():
    # Generate set of interference start with selected item interference above and add the neighbour interference to it to prevent overlapping or interfering with others
    neighbour_set = set(data['interference'])

    for sub_schedule_id, sub_data in interference_dict.items():
        if sub_schedule_id not in neighbour_set:
            neighbour_set = neighbour_set.union(sub_data['interference'])

    schedule_ids = [key for key in interference_dict.keys() if key not in neighbour_set]

    if schedule_ids not in [x[1] for x in profits]:
        profits.append(
            (sum([data_['time'] for key, data_ in interference_dict.items() if key not in neighbour_set]),
             schedule_ids))
print(profits)
```

The output of the code: list of (total time of non overlapping items, list of items not interfered)

```
[(38, [1, 2]), (73, [2, 3]), (85, [1, 4])]
```

My problem that my code miss other combinations like `(120, [3,4])`. 
If there is a better way to improve code I can easily change how `interference_dict` looks.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption 1. Any two schedules can be combined into a valid pair so far as there is no interference.
Assumption 2. If A interferes with B, i.e., A is in B's interference list, The opposite is also true

You can use itertools.combination to get all possible combinations and discard the invalid combinations.

```py
from itertools import combinations

valid_combinations = []
for a, b in interference_dict.items():
    # skip interfering combinations
    if a in interference_dict[b]["interference"]: continue
    valid_combinations.append((interference_dict[a]["time"]+interference_dict[b]["time"], [a,b]))

#Now sort be 0th value
valid_combinations.sort(key = lambda item:item[0])
```